# x86_64-pc-cygwin gcc compilation error

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Can someone help me to figure out this error.

I'm trying to compile a test program and it gives this error 
`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest`.

I gave correct path of lib `cc test.c -I"./include" -L"./Lib" -ltest`, still it is throwing error. Library is present in mentioned folder.

I tried too many things discussed over here but nothing helped me.

Comment: Do `ls Lib` and post the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Cygwin you should be able to build a library that generates the appropriate shared object with something like:

```
gcc -shared -o libtest.so -Wl,--out-implib,libtest.dll.a libtest.c
```

`libtest.c` would be the name of your `.c` file or a list of `.c` files used to build your library.

This should produce a `libtest.dll.a` and `libtest.so` . You use the import library to link your programs to the shared object. So you could compile your application with:

```
gcc test.c -I./include -LLib/ -ltest
```

The `Lib/libtest.dll.a` is a library (import library) that knows how to load the `.so` file at run-time.

To be more Windows like you could drop the `.so` suffix and use `.dll`. So compiling your shared object this way would work too:

```
gcc -shared -o libtest.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libtest.dll.a libtest.c
```

And then compile the client(test) as we did above:

```
gcc test.c -I./include -LLib/ -ltest
```

Because you compiled the shared object above with `-o libtest.dll` the import library that is created will now search for `libtest.dll` instead of `libtest.so` when your program is executed.

Please note that at run-time Windows searches your path for shared object (or dll). So you will have to move your shared object (or dll) to the directory you are running your application from; or copy your shared object (dll) to somewhere on your path; or add your `./Lib/` directory to your path.